# django.db model not found 'ForeignKey'

Tags: python, django

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE) 
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    locality= models.CharField(max_length=200) 
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    zipcode = models.IntegerField()
    state = models.CharField(choices=STATE_CHOICES, max_length=50)
```

This is a part of my code.

I have correctly imported models but unable to find the error.

Error message:

```
AttributeError: module 'django.db.models' has no attribute 'Foreignkey'
```

Comment: It is `ForeignKey` with a capital `K`, not a lowercase `k`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you posted is fine.

But You are using  Foreignkey and not **ForeignKey** (see the uppercase **K**) somewhere in your code.

Please check for the typo in your code and fix it.